# In LWC, component field has incoherent value in renderedCallback

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I encountered a very odd behaviour which I don't understand.
My component has the following code :

```js
myFocusOnRender = false;

handleResultClick(event) {
   this.myFocusOnRender = true;
   ...
}

renderedCallback(){
        if(this.myFocusOnRender){
            input.focus();
            this.myFocusOnRender = false;
        }
}
```

The issue is that when the `renderedCallback`  is triggered, my attribute `myFocusOnRender` is `false` however it is not set to `false` by any line in my component.

Do you have any clue about that ?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: You defaulted it to false on the first line in your code example?

Comment: Yes but it is set to true in my handler and this handler trigger the rendering

Comment: The LWC's initial rendering isn't something you trigger, it happens naturally.

Comment: When I say trigger, I mean the method updated reactive properties which triggers the component rendering. Sorry if it wasn’t clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after a thorough investigation, we found out that the component was disconnected from its parent and then reattached, I don't understand why since it's only supposed to be a rerender, but here is the workaround we came up with :

On the child component, have an event dispatched and a public `@api` method to focus the input :

```js
handleResultClick(event) {
  this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("focuslost"))
   ...
}

    focusInput(){
        this.template.querySelector(".slds-input").focus();
    }
```

And in the parent, call the method in a handler, with a `setTimeout`, in order to push the execution of the code behind the component lifecycle method on the event loop :

```js
    handleFocusLost() {
        setTimeout(() => this.template.querySelector('c-lookup').focusInput(), 0)
    }
```